# Graph permutation and rotation witn NetworkX

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, networkx, graph-theory, isomorphism

l work with Networkx to generate some class of graphs.

Now l would like to permute nodes and rotate the graph with (80°, 90°,120° degree)

How can l apply **permutation** and **rotation** on graphs with NetworkX ?

**Edit_1:**

Given an adjacency matrix of  a graph, l would like  to rotate the graph in the way that it preserves the edges and vertices link. The only thing that changes is the position of nodes.

What l would like to do is to rotate my graph with 90 degree.

**Input :**

Adjacency matrix of graph G

**process :**

Apply rotation on  G with 90 degree

**Output :**

Rotated adjacency matrix

It means, the graph preserves its topology and just the index of adjacency matrix that changes position.

For example nodes 1 at index 0 after rotation will be at index 4 for instance.

**What l have tried ?**
1)l looked after `numpy.random.permutation()` but it does't seem to accept the rotation parameter.

2) In networkX l didn't find any function that allows to do rotation.

**EDIT2**
Given an adjacency matrix of  5*5 (5 nodes:

```
adj=[[0,1,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,0]
]
```

l would like to permute between indexes .
Say that node 1 takes  the place of node 3 , node 3 takes the place of nodes 4  and node 4 takes the place of node 1.

It's just the permutation of nodes (preserving their edges).

l would like to keep in a dictionary the mapping between original index and the new index after permutation.

Secondly, l would like to apply permutation or rotation of this adjacency matrix with  an angle of 90°. (It's like apply rotation on an image). I'm not sure how it can be done.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and a desired output?

Comment: @Joel, please see my update. Hope it's clear

Comment: This still isn't clear to me.  It looks like you're talking about the (x,y) coordinates of the nodes, but then you also seem to be relabeling the nodes.  You don't need to relabel nodes to change the (x,y) coordinates. 
 Can you give a specific input and what the desired output for that input should be?

Comment: @Joel, please see my update example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the networkx command [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes).

Given a graph `G`, if we want to relabel node `0` as `1`, `1` as `3`, and `3` as `0` [so a permutation of the nodes, leaving `2` in place], we create the dict `mapping = {0:1, 1:3, 3:0}`.  Then we do

```
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
```

And `H` is now the permuted graph.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.path_graph(4)  #0-1-2-3
mapping = {0:1, 1:3, 3:0}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping) #1-3-2-0

#check G's adjacency matrix
print(nx.to_numpy_matrix(G,nodelist=[0,1,2,3]))
> [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]]

#check H's adjacency matrix
print(nx.to_numpy_matrix(H,nodelist=[0,1,2,3]))
> [[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  1.  1.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Joel. Now l need for a way to do a mapping automatically. Your example is random permutation. Now l need to  do an explicit permutation (rotation in a given sense with 90° or 70°) .

Comment: You still need to explain what 'rotation' means in the context of an adjacency matrix, @ericlardon.

Comment: Can you tell me what a rotation by 70 degrees would mean for the path network G I used?

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately is no longer working in the latest version of NetworkX (I'm using v2.3)!

Comment: Actually it works, the change is that `nx.to_numpy_matrix` is putting the nodes in a different order.  I've updated to make clearer