# Is it possible to create a graph permutation in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, permutation

I wrote a simple permutation function and I would like to graph its output. Is it even possible?

```py
from itertools import permutations

def permutate(string):
    letters = [x for x in string]
    perms = list(permutations(letters, len(letters)))
    p_set = set([''.join(i) for i in perms])

    return p_set


a = list(permutate('abab'))
# output: ['abba', 'abab', 'aabb', 'baba', 'baab', 'bbaa']
```

I have difficulties finding materials about permutation graph so any help would be appreciated.

This is what I would like to achieve

[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: 1- please provide your code as text, 2- please provide example datasets (as text) and explain how they generalize

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179002/graph-permutation-and-rotation-witn-networkx ...

Comment: So now, how does your list translate into the graphs?

Comment: @mozway my question is if I can even create a graph from a permutation, maybe I have to change my function to input integers and then plot given integers in the graph? I have no idea really

Comment: I think you could use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org). Since you have already generated the permutations, you have all the vertices. You just need to store in a dict maybe the element change relationships to get your edges. Sounds like a fun project.

Comment: @MartynaMajch I just don't get the logic of how to draw the graph, what are the numbers? How to choose how to link the values? Why 4 graphs?

Comment: @mozway sorry, I haven't specified my question. By "what I want to acheive" I meant the example of graph permutation itself. The numbers from  the photo will be replaced by letters from my function. If I can't make it based on letters then I will change my function to input integers.

Comment: It's not about the labels or how you represent your values. You have the string "abba". **How do you decide to represent a string as a graph?** Are the two "a"s unique? How do you decide which vertices share an edge with another based on the order of the letters in the string? Your code permutates the letters in a string. The image shows combinations of edges in a graph, where the number of edges probably varies from 0 to max.

Comment: If instead you have an iterable all with unique values, where each value represents the existence of a specific edge, e.g., 1-3, 4-6, etc, this will be easy to translate to a graph.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you do in your function, but found out how to make the graphs you want, using `networkx` and `matplotlib`.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 4), (2, 5),
                  (0, 5), (1, 5), (3, 5), (2, 4), (0, 2), (1, 3)])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
nx.draw(G, ax=axes, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]